# .htacces for api rest and admin panel

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

I have a website in laravel with this .htacces and work fine for my admin panel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but now I wrote an APP in Ionic that consume an api rest from my website and I cant access the server but if change the .htaccess to this, work for the APP but not the website

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

My error is “CAUTION: provisional headers are shown” and headers are not sent if I use the first .htacess.
I would like to know how to combine the two .htaccess, I tried this but doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please tell me what kind of error that showed up when the first time APP access the API

Comment: Hi @sinaxtis Please edit your question and show error message because easily identify which kind of error occur

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice